# JQuery trouble with sending ajax report

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to send report with this script:

```
$(".saveButton").on("click", function(){
 var setting = {
    'propertyName' : "SomeName",
    'propertyValue' : $(this).parent().siblings('.inputCol').children('.inputField').val();
 };
 $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/settings/PropertyEdit",
    data: JSON.stringify(setting ),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

And receive my POST in this method:

```
@Link(label = "Property Edit", family = "SettingsController", parent = "Settings")
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings/PropertyEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String atmPropertyEdit(Setting setting) {

     return "true";
}
```

However I can even stop into my breakpoint (on return) (`Error 403 - no-referrer-when-downgrade`), unless I change my request method to GET, then it works fine.

Have tried this script - same 403 error.

```
$.post('/atmsettings/atmPropertyEdit', { propertyName : "hello", propertyValue : "hello2"}, 
function(returnedData){
    console.log(returnedData);
});
```

Comment: Don't think you need to do `data: JSON.stringify(setting )` just `data: setting` should be okay

Comment: Your problem looks like a `CORS` problem though is the front-end host same as the backend?

Comment: @AyoK not sure if i understood you question correctly, but i am launching my project on a localhost in debug mode.

Comment: what's the url you enter on the browser? What is the url for the Spring service?